# This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension point identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm trying to execute an app with a SiriKit extension in a physical device (iPhone 7 and  iOS 11.1.2) with XCode 9.2.

The problem is that the app builds successfully, but it cannot been installed and an error appears:

[image]

- This key in the Info.plist extension is: **com.apple.intents-service**
- The minimim deployment target is **8.0**

Anyone knows what can be the problem? Could be that the deployment target should be higher?

Answer (score 2):

set the SiriKit Deployment Target version to 10.0

Answer (score 0):

The Target Version of extensions is different from that of the App. Sirikit requires SDK iOS 10+ to run, so you can set your app to 8, but your extension must be set to 10+.

Note: This means users below 10 will not have access to your sirikit extension features.